# Nested ng-repeat with <tr> <td>

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have my JSON data like this:

```json
{
  "results": [
    {
      "Header": "header1",
      "Sections": [
        {
          "Name": "sec1"
        },
        {
          "Name": "sec2"
        },
        {
          "Name": "sec3"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Header": "header2",
      "Sections": [
        {
          "Name": "sec4"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Header": "header3",
      "Sections": [
        {
          "Name": "sec5"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to display the data in a table layout like this:

```
    header1   | header2  |  header3
---------------------------------------
sec1|sec2|sec3|  sec4    |   sec5
```

I'm not able to do this with the following code:

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td ng-repeat="header in results" colspan="{{header.Sections.length}}">
       {{header.Header}}
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <div ng-repeat="header in results">
        <td ng-repeat="section in header.Sections">
          {{section.Name}}
        </td>
      </div>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I tried to use ng-repeat-start on the `<div>` but still couldn't get it to work. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**

The output with the current code is:

```
header1    |  header2   |  header3
```

Comment: can you please show what output you're having ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
angular.module("myApp", [])
  .controller("myController", function($scope) {
    $scope.results = [{
      "Header": "header1",
      "Sections": [{
        "Name": "sec1"
      }, {
        "Name": "sec2"
      }, {
        "Name": "sec3"
      }]
    }, {
      "Header": "header2",
      "Sections": [{
        "Name": "sec4"
      }]
    }, {
      "Header": "header3",
      "Sections": [{
        "Name": "sec5"
      }]
    }];
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<table ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td ng-repeat="header in results" colspan="{{header.Sections.length}}">
        {{header.Header}}
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td ng-repeat="header in results">
        <table><tr><td ng-repeat="section in header.Sections">
          {{section.Name}}
        </td></tr></table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

every header should be a column and every column should have a 1 row table of sections as colums .. see the snippet and tell me if this is what you wanted

Comment: I ran you code but all 5 sections were shown under header1

Comment: Inspect the generated tables and you will see it's structured right ,, it's just a matter of styling ..

Answer (score 0):

The key is to transform the data the way you need it laid out in the controller. In the below snippet I added a new function `allSections` that will retrieve a flat list of all sections so that an `ng-repeat` directive can loop over the entire list. I also added an `addSection` button to demonstrate that this updates properly when the number of sections changes. Hat tip to @AhmedEid for copying the code into a snippet in the first place.

```js
angular.module("myApp", [])
  .controller("myController", function($scope) {
    $scope.results = [{
      "Header": "header1",
      "Sections": [{
        "Name": "sec1"
      }, {
        "Name": "sec2"
      }, {
        "Name": "sec3"
      }]
    }, {
      "Header": "header2",
      "Sections": [{
        "Name": "sec4"
      }]
    }, {
      "Header": "header3",
      "Sections": [{
        "Name": "sec5"
      }]
    }];
  
    $scope.allSections = function() {
      var sections = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < $scope.results.length; i++) {
        var column = $scope.results[i];
        for (var j = 0; j < column.Sections.length; j++) {
          sections.push(column.Sections[j]);
        }
      }
      
      return sections;
    }
    
    $scope.addSection = function(header) {
      header.Sections.push({Name: "sec" + (header.Sections.length + 1)});
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<table ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td ng-repeat="header in results" colspan="{{header.Sections.length}}">
        {{header.Header}}
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td ng-repeat="section in allSections()">
          {{section.Name}}
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td ng-repeat="header in results" colspan="{{header.Sections.length}}">
        <button ng-click="addSection(header)">Add</button>
      </td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```